# How do i get posts from Twitter using PHP API?

Tags: php, twitter

This is my code:

```
require_once('api/TwitterAPIExchange.php');
    $settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token' => "xxxxxxx",
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxxxxx",
        'consumer_key' => " xxxxxxxx",
        'consumer_secret' => "xxxxxxxx"
    );
    $url = 'https://twitter.com/myuser';
    $requestMethod = 'POST';

    $postfields = array(
    'screen_name' => 'usernameToBlock', 
    'skip_status' => '1'
);

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
var_dump($twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->setPostfields($postfields)->performRequest());
```

The result of the var_dump is empty or nothing. What am i doing wrong ?

This is the perfomRequest function: The $json it is always null. Any idea ?

```
 public function performRequest($return = true, $curlOptions = array()){

        if (!is_bool($return)) {
            throw new Exception('performRequest parameter must be true or false');
        }

        $header =  array($this->buildAuthorizationHeader($this->oauth), 'Expect:');

        $getfield = $this->getGetfield();
        $postfields = $this->getPostfields();

        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false 
        ) + $curlOptions;

        if (!is_null($postfields)) {
            $options[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query($postfields);
        }
        else{
            if ($getfield !== '')
            {
                $options[CURLOPT_URL] .= $getfield;
            }
        }
        $feed = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);

        $json = curl_exec($feed);

        if (($error = curl_error($feed)) !== '')
        {

            curl_close($feed);

            throw new \Exception($error);
        }
        curl_close($feed);

        return $json;
    }
```

I added this: CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false  to my function. I saw in forums that is solves the problem, but in my case NOT .Can someone help me ?

Comment: now it is fine, but it is not a syntax error. Here you can see the result: http://test.attila-naghi.com/. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: it is done, and still the same, no erros, no warnings, no notice. This is the first time when i use this API

Comment: If I do var dump to this:  var_dump($twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)->setPostfields($postfields)); it shows me smth

Comment: I went to this function and the return $json is empty, any idea?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeMoldovan - original dev here. Have you tried grabbing the **latest version** of this file, on Github? Could you open an issue there? Also, if you want to debug yourself, `var_dump(curl_error($feed));` before the `curl_close()` call.